# Why is a value not being returned?

Tags: c#, .net, return

Unsure why I am getting this error...this is the method (I believe I am returning all the necessary values). Does anybody have an idea of what i am missing syntax-wise, or do you think that the problem bigger than in just this stack trace?

```
public bool equals(Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (GetType() != obj.GetType())
    {
        return false;
    }

    AccountNumber anotherObj = (AccountNumber) obj;

    if (failedCheckSum != anotherObj.failedCheckSum)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (notValid != anotherObj.notValid)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (line0 == null)
    {
        if (anotherObj.line0 != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!line0.Equals(anotherObj.line0))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (line1 == null)
        {
            if (anotherObj.line1 != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (!line1.Equals(anotherObj.line1))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (line2 == null)
        {
            if (anotherObj.line2 != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (!line2.Equals(anotherObj.line2))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Well, you are not telling us what the error is, or what line it is on. We are not mind readers.  BTW, it is bad practice to have all these explicit returns in the method.  Better to set a variable and then have one return at the end.

Comment: You need one more return statement outside the last braket

Comment: You say "stack trace" so I have to assume this is a run time error.  bool is not nullable.  If you did not return a value by accident then the code will not compile.  So the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You have to ensure that your method returns a value along *every possible* code path. In your method, if `line0 != null` it will fall through the last `if` block without having any value to return.

The easiest way to solve this would be to add a `return` statement at the very end of your method, like this:

```
public bool equals(Object obj)
{
    ...

    return false; // or true, depending on how you want it to behave
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning a value on the last line.

You have a series of if statements that return a value. If none of those expressions is true though, execution flow will fall through to the end of the method, where you have no return.

Answer (score 0):

Follow through with the recommendation and pay attention to the notes - this really *does* address the issue.

Consider rewriting all of your:

```
if (anotherObj.line1 != null)
{
    return false;
}
else if (!line1.Equals(anotherObj.line1))
{
    return false;
}
```

Using [object.Equals(object,object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then it looks more like:

```
if (!object.Equals(line1, anotherObj.line1)) {
  return false;
}
```

Making this change also reveals that `if (line0 == null) {` opens up an *incorrect nesting*<sup>1</sup>. This can be further seen if using logical operators to group multiple conditions within a single `if..return false` construct.

The changes should make the "missing return" (which is the cause of the error) easy to find.

---

<sup>1</sup> I propose that this *is* the core problem with the presented code as the `return true` is *inside* that conditional block and thus there is an execution path without a return.

---

Also, make sure to *actually* override `bool Equals(object)`. The above `equals` differs in case and thus does not override said method.